# cocos2d with html popup window on xcode

Tags: html, xcode, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

i am using cocos2d and i want to add simple popup with HTML to my project. 
this is the project for XIB - https://github.com/icanzilb/MTPopupWindow
but i want to add it to cocoa2d project.

When i add this code to my -(id) init{

```
[MTPopupWindow showWindowWithHTMLFile:@"testContent.html" insideView:self.view];
```

}

Its crushing because it searching the "VIEW" but i dont have a view .

so i am asking how can i create simple HTML POPUP window on my project xcode

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to [CCDirector sharedDirector].view and see if that works.

Comment: Can you help me with more information it will help me

Comment: Try: [MTPopupWindow showWindowWithHTMLFile:@"testContent.html" insideView:[CCDirector sharedDirector].view];

Comment: i am getting this  error - "Property 'view' not found on object of type 'CCDirector'

Comment: What version of cocos2d are you using? If it is really old try openGLView or something of that nature. Check the header file.

Comment: If you go to the link above and try to if you can of course to help me .. .To convert it to cocos2d line .

Comment: I've already answered the question above. Are you new to programming and/or cocos2d? Assuming you have a simple scene that you are just trying to add the popup to, just add that code to either the scene's init or onEnter and see if it works. Based on the question I assumed you already knew how to use that popup library you are working with and that you know cocos2d. It should be self explanatory.

Comment: Sir, 
i already add it to init but the error is that i dont have VIEW like the error above
i am getting this error - "Property 'view' not found on object of type 'CCDirector'.

i know its simple thing for you but for me it isnt ...

Comment: You want the code to take a look what is wrong...
cus i didnt found how to fix this error.

Comment: I just woke up and saw your email. I'm glad you fixed it. Please update your original question with what you've done to fix it. Glad it worked out.